# how 2 wpf application can talk to each other

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a scenerio,

I have 2 application which are WPF application App1 and Console Application App 2. I need to get the Application object from APP1 in APP2. So that I can use the method App1.Shutdown().

Since I need to get the Application Exit event for APP1, I cannot use Process.Kill from APP2.

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: Why can't you use the `Process.Exited` event? Then you could use `Process.Kill`.

Comment: Nope, Process.Exited never occurs because technically the APP has been killed and all the resource associated with the app has been removed by the OS.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/05/10/605.aspx) is the simplest approach you can try in which one process can send message to another one based on that you can take action. In your case you can send msg *"shutdown"* to another process then at receiver end you can call ***App.Shutdown()***

Comment: Well this could work if both App or at least the receiving app is in Activate state (meaning not Iconized). If it is minized and iconized, then the receving app never receives the message.

Answer (score 0):

A Simple and effective way is to use TCP communication between both application. APP 1 could send a message to predefined Port and on the other end when the APP2 receives the message, it can shutdown by it own.